# Problem in zooming of UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone

In my application i used an UIImageView in UIScrollView and i used code for that.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 

{

scrollV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);

  [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

{

    return imageView;
}
```

the code working fine but when i placing UIButton on the imageView of scrollView and after i zooming the scrollV, the imageView zoom perfectly according to scrollView but UIButton and not be zoomed.

I want when i zoom the imageview, the buttons i placed on imageView also be zoom with respect to zoomed imageView.

Comment: @Jacob Relkin, do you have any idea on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got success to find out the solution of above question.I written the for that,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 

{

    bgViewOfImage.contentStretch = CGRectMake(ImageView.frame.origin.x, ImageView.frame.origin.y, ImageView.frame.size.width, ImageView.frame.size.height);
    scrollV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(bgViewOfImage.frame.size.width, bgViewOfImage.frame.size.height);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

{

    return bgViewOfImage;
}
```

I creating an hierarchy inserting an UIView on main view then i dragging other controls like UIImageview's and UIButtons on it.Now it perfectly working and zooming each control.

Answer (score 1):

Create a proxy UIView instance as scrollview's subview and place all UI elements you want to be zoomed into it. Then return that view from `viewForZoomingInScrollView` method

Answer (score 0):

```
    CGSize imageView = [photo size];
    UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)[self view];
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [scrollView setContentSize:photoSize];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

    // Create the image view.
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, photoSize.width, photoSize.height)];
    [imageView setImage:photo];
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    // Configure zooming.
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat widthRatio = screenSize.width / photoSize.width;
    CGFloat heightRatio = screenSize.height / photoSize.height;
    CGFloat initialZoom = (widthRatio > heightRatio) ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    [scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:3.0];
    [scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:initialZoom];
    [scrollView setZoomScale:initialZoom];
    [scrollView setBouncesZoom:YES];

    // Center the photo.
    CGFloat topInset = (screenSize.height - photoSize.height * initialZoom) / 2.0;
    if (topInset > 0.0)
    {
        [scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset - 44.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imageView;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGSize photoSize = [photo size];
    CGFloat topInset = (screenSize.height - photoSize.height * [scrollView zoomScale]) / 2.0;
    if (topInset < 0.0)
    {
        topInset = 0.0;
    }

    [scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(topInset, 0.0, -topInset, 0.0)];
}
```